# Else if statement within a calc() type method returning the incorrect value

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

```
public double calcTuition()
    {
        if (isGraduating == 'y')
        {
            return (Math.round((creditHours * 90.00 * 100.0))) / 100.0;
        }
        else if (isGraduating == 'n' && creditHours > 21)
        {
            return (Math.round(1000.0 + (creditHours - 21) * 90.00 * 100.0)) /100.0;
        }
        else if (isGraduating == 'n')
        {
            return (Math.round((1000.0 * 100.0))) /100.0;
        }

    }
```

I have this snippet of java code here that keeps telling me that It is not returning a double as it is supposed to, it is baffling me as to why. The only thing I could think of was the 'creditHours' are int's so i casted them to doubles and it made no difference. Should i be using a case statement here rather than else if?

EDIT: Thank you so much for the incredibly quick responses. It was actually quite surprising to be honest, I mean, looking at the stupid error I made I don't know how half of you answer these, I'm sure over and over, and still have the patience to make them thought provoking answers. As soon as I heard bronco say "default" in his post I knew exactly what was wrong. 
Thanks again this is really a fantastic community.

Comment: What happens if **none** of those `if` clauses are satisfied?

Comment: If `isGraduating` is always either 'y' or 'n', the final `else if` should be a simple `else`. If `isGraduating` can have any other value, you need to say what to do in that case.

Comment: @user2967104 Please accept broncoAbierto's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the compiler sees is what to do in three cases, but it has no way to know what to do by default. What if none of the `if` conditions returns true?

In order to get your program to work, you should add a return statement by default, or make the last `else if` just an `else`

Answer (score 0):

You can always insert a debug line before returning so you can see what the actual value is.

You should always return some kind of value in java, in this code all of the cases could be false so you would not have a double to return.